# How to select records according to a combination of multiple values coming from another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have 3 tables. The relationship between `students` and `articles` is **many-to-many** through `student_articles`.

students:

```
-----------------------
id      name       ...
-----------------------
1       Alex          
2       Bob         
3       Cathy         
...
```

articles:

```
------------------------             
id      title  ...          
------------------------            
1       A                         
2       B                         
3       C                          
...
```

student_articles:

```
-------------------------------------             
id      student_id  article_id  ...          
-------------------------------------         
1       1            1             
2       3            1             
3       1            2   
4       3            2  
...
```

Now I'd like to SELECT `articles` that are written by and exactly by Alex and Cathy (at least article 1 and 2 should be selected according to the information above), how should I write my SQL query? In this example, `["Alex", "Cathy"]` is what I mean by "a combination of multiple values" in the title. And the combination come as a variable. So, desirably, the query should be adaptive and neat even if the list of student names is a large one (like containing more than 10 names).

BTW, I'm using **PostgreSQL 10.1**. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having no Postgress at at hand it's more a guess, but following the documentition it could be sometihing like

```
SELECT * FROM articles 
INNER JOIN student_articles ON student_articles.article_id = articles.id AND  
INNER JOIN students ON student_articles.student_id = students.id 
GROUP BY articles.id
HAVING array_agg(students.name)::text[] @> ARRAY['Alex','Cathy'] AND array_agg(students.name)::text[] <@ ARRAY['Alex','Cathy']
```

Comment: Thanks man. Actually `array_agg` was what I was looking for. But you helped me find it out. If you don't mind, I will make some edits to your answer and then accept it.

Comment: Thank you for improving it, having me learning more about postgress

Comment: Just to be clear for those having the same question. Use both "@>" and "<@" if you want to ignore the order of elements when comparing the arrays. (I guess that's the right way to do it. But at least it works for me) Otherwise, use "=".

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    z.id    as article_id,
    z.title
from
    students x join student_articles y on x.id = y.student_id
        join articles z on y.article_id = z.id
where
    x.name = 'Alex'
intersect
select 
    z.id    as article_id,
    z.title
from
    students x join student_articles y on x.id = y.student_id
        join articles z on y.article_id = z.id
where
    x.name = 'Cathy'
except
select 
    z.id    as article_id,
    z.title
from
    students x join student_articles y on x.id = y.student_id
        join articles z on y.article_id = z.id
where
    x.name not in ('Alex', 'Cathy');
```

Result:

```
 article_id | title 
------------+-------
          2 | B
          1 | A
(2 rows)
```

This is a properly structured many-to-many relationship so it makes it easy to get the right answer using standard SQL.  You might want to look at http://www.thedatastudio.net for more SQL examples.

Thanks to Turo for pointing out the flaw in my first attempt.  The code above takes care of this now.  I added the following rows to test this:

```
insert into articles (id, title) values (4, 'D');
insert into student_articles (id, student_id, article_id) values (5, 1, 4);
insert into student_articles (id, student_id, article_id) values (6, 2, 4);
insert into student_articles (id, student_id, article_id) values (7, 3, 4);
```

That is a title "D" written by Alex, Cathy **and** Bob.  The earlier version would have included this as well.

Comment: You've missed the 'exactly by Alex and Cathy' part

Comment: Ah, I should exclude the case where there is another author as well as Alex and Cathy.  Will do.